# Webservice Call failure

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a webservice call as below:

```
public void getServiceSessionId() throws Exception{
    InfrastructureService service1 = new InfrastructureService();
    InfrastructureServiceSoap port1 = service1.getInfrastructureServiceSoap();
    LoginRequestType loginR = new LoginRequestType();
}
```

And call fails during the initialization itself for the `InfraStructureService()`. It doesn't throw any error and instead it is going to the bottom of the stack, when am trying to test through my eclipse IDE.

This `InfrastructureService()` method is a *JAX-WS* auto generated service implementation file for the *WSDL*.

I am able to open the *WSDL* in the IE and also able to obtain the session id through *SOAP UI*.

How can I rectify this error and make my program run?

I was able to obtain the exception it throws and below is the Stack Trace:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument.setDocumentURI(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1066)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:98)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Unknown Source)
    at com.t.webservices.cqc.cae.infra.infrastructue.InfrastructureService.(InfrastructureService.java:41)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.caws.CAWebServiceClient.getServiceSessionId(CAWebServiceClient.java:186)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.caws.CAWebServiceClient.createCaseRequest(CAWebServiceClient.java:222)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.Referral278CAWebServiceHelper.createCaseRequest(Referral278CAWebServiceHelper.java:1555)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.Referral278Processor.createUmCase(Referral278Processor.java:4038)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.Referral278Processor.createInitialResponse(Referral278Processor.java:4158)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.Referral278Processor.getProcessInitialRequest(Referral278Processor.java:216)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.Referral278Main.processRequest(Referral278Main.java:130)
    at com.b.ca.referrals278.Referral278Main.main(Referral278Main.java:49)

Comment: Can you provide _any_ stacktrace for the error?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for replying back. Any exception is not thrown it just gets out of the function InfrastructureService() and goes to the bottom of the stack and exits out of the program.

Comment: Hi Paul, I have included the stack trace above, can u please help me now